# CP invalid option error

Tags: grep, terminal, cp, xargs, gnome-terminal

I'm getting an error that I can't make heads or tails of when trying to use cp through xargs

```
grep -l -r .mp4 * | xargs cp -t ./Destination
```

Results in

```
cp: invalid option -- 'G'
```

The goal here is to search through the current folder, and copy all mp4 files to the folder Destination. I don't understand where the error message is getting the 'G' from though, as I'm not calling any option G, or even using the character G at all in the CP argument!

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here please? If it makes a difference i'm using the stock terminal window in a pretty fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: Is there a file whose name starts with `-G`?  Do you still get the error with `[...] | xargs cp -t -- ./Destination`?

Comment: Try doing `xargs cp -t -- ./Destination`

Comment: what if you substitute "xargs cp...." with "xargs echo"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, sadly no dice.Using `[...] | xargs cp -t -- ./Destination` just gives me `cp: failed to access '--': No such file or directory`   Also no, no file starts with -G

Comment: Xargs echo gives me a readout of the filenames. The only thing I can think of that seems potentially odd here is that the filenames all have spaces in them, could that be causing issues?

Comment: The `--` needs to go after the target directory `./Destination` - but more importantly, `xargs` splits on whitespace by default, so your pipeline will still break on filenames that contain whitespace. Try adding `-Z` to the grep options and `-0` to the `xargs`.

Comment: @steeldriver That did the job, thank you! To make sure I understood what I just did since I'm still learning this; from reading the manuals it looks like the `-Z` told grep to output a null character at the end of each file name, and the `-0` told xargs to ignore whitespaces and instead look for that null character, does that sound right?What did the `--` at the end do? I couldn't find that explained anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

@steeldriver figured this out in the comments of the main question. The issue was being caused by whitespace in the filenames and modifying the command to `grep -l -r -Z '.mp4' * | xargs -0 cp -t ./Test --` sorted it!